# Copy between Win Servers, which protocol?

Tags: networking, windows-server-2008

If I copy data between to Windows Server disk folders (e.g. so that there is fileshare in the other computer), what is the protocol in this copying? Both of these computers are under the same domain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows file sharing uses the [Server Message Block (SMB) protocol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Message_Block).